# How to split a string to non empty words if it might include a separator like tab on first place

Tags: java, regex

I have a strings that I want to split on words. I use `String[] words = line.split("\\s+");` Problem that some if some them start with tab separator like "\t word1 \t word2....". then as a result of split I get array with 1st element "", 2nd "word1", 3rd: "word2" ... How to modify expression split("\s+") if I don't want to get any empty "" words in split result? (Result of split should have 1st element: "word1")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to [trim](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim()) the word in the first place, so you no longer have spaces before the first character and after the last one, and then you could start splitting.

Example :

```
String[] words = line.trim().split("\\s+");
```